# LibGdx project setup - Project generated with gradle error

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to generate the LibGdx based project using the tool gdx-setup.jar

I am getting some strange errors that I have not faced before. Could you please assist me in generating the project successfully ?

> Generating app in C:\Games\Jewel Games New
>       Executing 'C:\Games\Jewel Games New/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon'
>       To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon:
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
>       Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
>
> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * Where:
> Build file 'C:\Games\Jewel Games New\build.gradle' line: 57
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Jewel Games New'.
> > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version
> ```
>
> 52.0
>
> ```
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 16s
> Done!
> To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Gradle Project
> To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> build.gradle
> To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

`major.minor version 52.0` error is possibly because the jar was compiled in JDK 1.8, but you are trying to run it using a JDK 1.7 environment.

To solve this, it's always better to have the JDK and JRE pointed to the same version.

Comment: I have changed the path variable to point 1.8 ... what additional steps needed for resolution.. Please assist

Comment: try to create new project using `gdx-setup.jar`